# MVC Bootstrap popup windows don't show properly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the problem with all popup windows. They show but the css is a total mess
http://s21.postimg.org/z35pliu7b/datepicker.jpg
I'm using MVC 5.2, Bootstrap 3.3 and jQuery 2.1
And this is my cshtml file

```
    @using BetTracker.App_GlobalResources
@model BetTracker.Models.TipsterModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DueDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "duedate" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DueDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#duedate').datepicker({
        });
    })
</script>
```

And this is what I'm rendering in my Layout:

```
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

I don't know what else would be helpful to show but any help to fix the problem and make the popup windows show properly would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: do you have error in browser console ?

Comment: We need to check the CSS files

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pk1zgdse/ this is my Site.css and these are the css styles from console and the rest of the files(I didn't touch them)
http://s13.postimg.org/4t4b4xrvr/cssconsole.jpg
http://s13.postimg.org/54lrhp8br/csss.jpg

Comment: You have to _debug_ what is **finally** rendered based on all those stylesheets you are rendering and figure out any/all conflicts/overridden styles, etc.. Use readily available browser dev tools for it. You can't expect anyone here to do that for you.

Comment: is @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") rendering after bootstrap. This should be as your themes will override any bootstrap css.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Seems like NuGet package of jquerUI didn't install corectly.It has added this to the Bundles :

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
          "~/Content/themes/base/*.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

But since my files don't have a jquery.ui. prefix, the bundle can't find them.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
          "~/Content/themes/base/*.css",
          ));
```